How can I solve "No file or directory found at ./my_model/model.h5" thrown by tf.keras.models.load_model?
I created a code that tells if a picture of a wave is a raging wave when I enter it into the code. The code is shown below.
pip install tensorflow opencv-python

import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# 모델 경로 설정 및 확인
model_dir = './my_model'
model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'model.h5')  # TensorFlow 모델 파일 확장자는 일반적으로 .h5입니다.
if not os.path.exists(model_path):
    print(f"The specified model path does not exist: {model_path}")
    exit()  # 프로그램을 종료


# 모델 로드 함수
def load_model(model_path):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)
    return model

# 웹캠에서 이미지 캡처 및 예측을 수행하는 함수
def capture_image(model):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # 0은 기본 카메라
    if not cap.isOpened():
        raise Exception("Cannot open webcam")

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Failed to grab frame")
            break

        # 이미지 프레임을 모델 입력에 맞게 전처리
        processed_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))  # 모델에 따라 조정 필요
        processed_frame = processed_frame / 255.0
        processed_frame = np.expand_dims(processed_frame, axis=0)

        # 예측 수행
        predictions = model.predict(processed_frame)
        predicted_class = np.argmax(predictions)
        confidence = np.max(predictions)

        # 결과 출력
        cv2.putText(frame, f'Class: {predicted_class}, Confidence: {confidence:.2f}',
                    (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        # 이미지 출력
        cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# 모델 로드
model = load_model(model_path)

# 웹캠 이미지 캡처 및 예측
capture_image(model)

But I got a problem.
# 모델 로드 함수
def load_model(model_path):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)
    return model

The above code showed "No file or directory found at ./my_model/model.h5" problem. How can I fix it?
I try changing picture name, add new code like below:
model.save("model.h5")
model = load_model('model.h5')

and I recently add some code to import os, cv2, numpy as np, tensorflow as tf.

Have you tried using an absolute path rather than a relative one ? Depending on your IDE parameters, the default working directory can be a different folder than the one where your script is located. The relative path would therefore be looking in the wrong folder.

learn about the current working directory. print(os.getcwd())

try to include full path for model_dir
for example
model_dir = r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\my_model"

